# Как отловить одиночный Tap на MapView?(Double)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Доброго времени суток! Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но на него не нашлось ответа.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отловить одиночный `tap` на карте `mapview`?
Пока что обошелся вот таким костылем, но может кто-то подскажет элегантное решение?

```
private boolean tap = false;  
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                       if(tap)
                          Toast.makeText(context, "tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        tap = true;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        tap = false;
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**UPD:** google maps api v1

Comment: какую версию карт ты используешь?

Comment: первую, обновил в топике

Answer (score 1):

[Detecting Common Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

> Жест происходит, когда пользователь помещает один или несколько пальцев на сенсорный экран, и приложение интерпретирует последовательность касаний как особый жест.

Comment: нет :(
к сожалению это не работает